# How to export neo4j data to csv/json

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, neo4jrestclient

I am using Neo4j Python REST Client and I want to use D3.js for the visualisation of my data.
I am creating the data like this:

```
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
alice = gdb.nodes.create(name="Alice",isTeacher=False)
bob = gdb.nodes.create(name="Bob"isTeacher=True)
bob.relationships.create("Knows", alice,strength = 0.4)
```

Is it possible to transform my data into json/csv in order to use that in D3?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you already try? Please check the examples linked here: http://neo4j.org/develop/visualize

Comment: @MichaelHunger I tried to export the json file but it does not return anything useful.

Comment: What json file, where, how?

Comment: @MichaelHunger there is a button next to the full screen one that is the "Export Json" in the web browser of Neo4j (http://localhost:7474/browser/). It just downloads a json file to the disk.

Comment: @user1855165: what command is the command line version equivalent of pressing that "Export Json" button in neo4j shell?

Comment: From the sounds of it, you're using neo4j 1.x. I too had issues exporting. I believe neo4j 2.x has dramatically improved visualization tools. While this isn't an easy option for me personally, I recommend anyone who wants to do this make sure they use Neo4j 2+ even if it's more effort than installing via a package manager.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of `neo4jrestclient`, there is an [option](https://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/queries.html#graph-and-row-data-contents) to return the data of a query as a list of rows or as a graph representation. So, you could run a query and use that.

```
results = gdb.query("MATCH (n)--() RETURN n", data_contents=True)
print(results.rows)
print(results.graph)
```

Only working for Neo4j 2.0+, though. In future releases, `QuerySequence` objects like `results`, will have `to_csv()` and `to_json()` helpers.